# grid in vsc for jade files

Tags: pug, visual-studio-code

I am using VSC, and wondering if there is a way to default .jade files to have a "grid-like" format so that it's easy to see if I've got my spacing just right. In other words, some very faint vertical lines or marks that give a background of where your spacing is at. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option you can enable to display indent lines. Add the following to your settings file:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

For more information about different settings, view the [user and workspace settings documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!